# Why does this ip address give me an error "must be valid ipv4 cidr"?

Tags: ipv4, subnet, ip-address, networking

If I set up an AWS VPC with CIDR of 10.0.0.0/20 then the range is 10.0.0.0 to 10.0.15.255 
I make a subnet now. Why does 10.0.15.15/28 give an error. Isn't it's range 10.0.15.15 to 10.0.15.30 which is within the VPC?

Comment: /28 is 16 addresses. 0-15, 16-31, etc. (0 and 15 -- all-zeros and all-ones addresses -- are reserved for network and broadcast)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Isn't it's range 10.0.15.15 to 10.0.15.30 which is within the VPC?

Yes, but it's not a valid /28.

10.0.15.0/28 or 10.0.15.16/28 are valid ranges.

Comment: For more details on CIDR subnetting, check out this primer over at Server Fault: https://serverfault.com/questions/12854/cidr-for-dummies

Comment: Why isn't it a valid /28 and why should it be a multiple of 16 ?

Comment: A /28 subnet requires the lowest four bits - the host bits - to be all zero.

Comment: @AkramElectroTech, if you read and understand [this two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499), you will see where you have gone wrong.